# Error while generating PDF for Japanese language

Tags: itext

We are facing the below error (sometimes) for iTextSharp PDF creation in Japanese language:

Exception: Font 'HeiseiKakuGo-W5' with 'UniJIS-UCS2-H' is not recognized.

we have already added reference for iTextAsian dll.

Let us know, if anybody have solution on this.

Comment: The word "sometimes" in your question indicates that it works most of the times (for instance: when I test it, it works), but that you have cases where it doesn't work. I think that this question can only be answered if you provide such a case where it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you Bruno Lowagie,

There is no specific case, it stops working suddenly, 
For some instances, if reset the IIS, it will work, but not sure for this.

Let me know your feedback.